# Google Cloud DLP tag in Data Catalog shows as Job State as pending?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp, google-data-catalog

I have first created a custom template in DLP (with custom detectors) and then created a DLP job using the new DLP template against a BQ table and ran the job with publish to Data Catalog setting.

The DLP job completed but the DLP tag in Data Catalog has the job state as pending...this only happens when I use Custom templates for DLP job.

If I use out of the box DLP detectors tag shows up correctly Data Catalog. Any idea why the custom DLP template results are not showing in Data Catalog?

Here is the o/p of the list tag for the BQ table entry in Data Catalog

```
   "name":"projects/XXXX/locations/US/entryGroups/@bigquery/entries/XXXX",
   "template":"projects/XXXX/locations/us-central1/tagTemplates/data_loss_prevention",
   "fields":{ 
      "job_name":{ 
         "displayName":"DLP job name",
         "stringValue":"projects/XXXX/dlpJobs/i-Copy-of-test_dlp_job4"
      },
      "job_state":{ 
         "displayName":"DLP job state",
         "stringValue":"PENDING"
      }
   },
   "templateDisplayName":"Data Loss Prevention Annotations"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you follow the documentation?

> https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-templates-inspect
>   https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/quickstart-create-template-inspect#create-template

I recommend you to perform this task again and go to stackdriver logging and look for the logs, maybe as this is a custom template you need to set an additional permission, however I can’t see your project and logs. Another thing you could try is to change the values, have you tried to change the Likelihood to unspecified or create a simple template like the default ones?